# Who can see closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I think I had this clear, but [it seems I don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299429/354477). I had the idea that closed questions can not be searched on Google, and can only be seen by the users of a given site with more than [250 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes).

Who can see closed questions? Can anyone see these questions from Google? If so, what is the point of having a 250 reputation threshold?

Note: this is not about what/when/how to close a question (as the post linked). It's about **viewing** closed questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everybody can see closed questions (before they are deleted), but only people with [at least 10,000 reputation](/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and ♦ moderators can see deleted questions. (Or the owner of such deleted question or one of the answers.)

The **view close votes** is *not* "seeing closed questions". People with [at least 3,000 rep](/help/privileges/close-questions) can vote to close **your own question**. With [at least 250 reputation](/help/privileges/view-close-votes), you can see something like `close (2)` on your own question, where 2 should be the number of "currently active close votes". When that number reaches 5 (or [3 for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391832/we-re-lowering-the-close-reopen-vote-threshold-from-5-to-3-for-good)), your question is closed.

See [help center](/help/privileges):

[image]

Comment: We can see spam, it's just one click away. Saying 10k or mods can't see spam is wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure if I can see the Q when I have an answer on a deleted question.

Comment: Spam: yes, it's just hidden behind a warning message but it links to the revisions where you can see it all. Having deleted answer: yes, it's pretty recent change (maybe year or so), owners of answers on deleted question can see their answer and the question, not the other answers.